# Why aren't my cards aligning properly in bootstrap 5?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

so I have been trying to work with prepared statements into order to make my PHP more secure.

I need to display products from a db table and without using prepared statements, the cards align as they should.

However, with a prepared statement, somewhere, somehow, I have made the cards not align in the right grid.

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Website Title</title>
      <?php 
         include 'navbar.php';
         include 'dbConnect.php';
         
         $results=$db->query("SELECT * FROM Stock");
         ?>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container-xl">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
               <p class="text-muted"> Home > viewStock.php </p>
               <h1 class="display-6">Shop
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container-xl">
         <?php while($row=$results->fetch_array())
            {
            ?>
         <form name="orderForm" method="post" action="viewProduct.php">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
               <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Stock No: <?php echo $row['stockID'] ?></h5>
                     <input type="hidden" name="stockID" value="<?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>">
                     <span class="card"><img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="No image yet"></span>
                     <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        <li class="list-group-item">Description: <?php echo $row['category'] ?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Quantity In Stock: <?php echo $row['qtyInStock'] ?></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">Price: £<?php echo $row['price'] ?></li>
                     </ul>
                     <p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">VIEW</button></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </form>
         <?php } ?>
      </div>
      <!-- end row --> 
   </body>
   <!-- Footer-->
   <footer class="container-xl py-5 bg-light">
      <div class="container">
         <p class="m-0 text-center text-black">Copyright &copy; The Music Store 2021</p>
      </div>
   </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi James. IF you are interested in becoming a professional PHP developer might I recommend you learn modern PHP? The way you are approaching this problem has been outdated in favor of newer techniques that leverage APIs, JavaScript, and other technologies. Modern architecture decouples the view from the data. Good for you learning new technology, but you are headed the wrong way. I would recommend you find a platform like Drupal and learn all about it, then you can begin a career with that under your belt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems, and I have a few suggestions.

- You don't really need separate containers for everything. I usually only have one on a page unless I need them to behave differently.
- The container with the form lacks a row. Every column should be inside a row.
- You have a form between the row and each column. Forms should be part of the column content, not mixed in with the layout grid.
- You probably don't want to be setting a fixed width on your cards, since each is in a column of its own. If you were just using a set of cards which flowed independently you could do that.

If we fix those issues things seem to work well. Here's your code with my changes.

```
<div class="container-xl">
  <div class="row">
    <?php while($row=$results->fetch_array()) { ?>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <form name="orderForm" method="post" action="viewProduct.php">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stock No:
              <?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>
            </h5>
            
            <input type="hidden" name="stockID" value="<?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>">
       
            <span class="card">
                <img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="No image yet">
            </span>
                
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">Description:
                <?php echo $row['category'] ?>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Quantity In Stock:
                <?php echo $row['qtyInStock'] ?>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Price: £
                <?php echo $row['price'] ?>
              </li>
            </ul>
            
            <p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">VIEW</button></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a mockup of the output. I've repeated the columns in your HTML for demonstration.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-xl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <form name="orderForm" method="post" action="viewProduct.php">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stock No:
              <?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>
            </h5>
            <input type="hidden" name="stockID" value="<?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>">
            <span class="card"><img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="No image yet"></span>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">Description:
                <?php echo $row['category'] ?>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Quantity In Stock:
                <?php echo $row['qtyInStock'] ?>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Price: £
                <?php echo $row['price'] ?>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">VIEW</button></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <form name="orderForm" method="post" action="viewProduct.php">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stock No:
              <?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>
            </h5>
            <input type="hidden" name="stockID" value="<?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>">
            <span class="card"><img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="No image yet"></span>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">Description:
                <?php echo $row['category'] ?>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Quantity In Stock:
                <?php echo $row['qtyInStock'] ?>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Price: £
                <?php echo $row['price'] ?>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">VIEW</button></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <form name="orderForm" method="post" action="viewProduct.php">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stock No:
              <?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>
            </h5>
            <input type="hidden" name="stockID" value="<?php echo $row['stockID'] ?>">
            <span class="card"><img class="img-fluid card-img-top" src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="No image yet"></span>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item">Description:
                <?php echo $row['category'] ?>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Quantity In Stock:
                <?php echo $row['qtyInStock'] ?>
              </li>
              <li class="list-group-item">Price: £
                <?php echo $row['price'] ?>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p align="center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">VIEW</button></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with your original code modified.